# How to resize image using Codeigniter

Tags: php, image, codeigniter, image-resizing

I am trying to upload image and resizing image.I want both image original image as well as thumb image.

But the problem is image resizing code is not working.

Image uploading code is working fine its store the image in folder but the image resizing code is not working.

How can i do this ?

Here is my Code

```
public function add_images(){

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('description','Description','required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('status','Status','required');

    if($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE) {
         // print_r($this->input->post());
        $config['upload_path'] = 'public/img/inner_images/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|jpeg|png';   // upload only valid images            
        // update library setting of upload
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
        //upload image 
        $this->upload->do_upload('image');
        $fInfo = $this->upload->data(); // get all info of uploaded file

        //for image resize
        $img_array = array();
        $img_array['image_library'] = 'gd2';
        $img_array['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
        $img_array['create_thumb'] = TRUE;
        //you need this setting to tell the image lib which image to process
        $img_array['source_image'] = $fInfo['full_path'];
        $img_array['width'] = 113;
        $img_array['height'] = 75;

        $this->load->library('image_lib', $img_array);

        if (!$this->image_lib->resize())
        {
            echo $this->image_lib->display_errors(); exit;
        }

        if($fInfo['file_ext'] ==='.gif'||$fInfo['file_ext'] ==='.jpg'|| $fInfo['file_ext'] ==='.jpeg' || $fInfo['file_ext'] ==='.png'|| $fInfo['file_ext'] ===''){
            $insert = array(
                'inner_image' =>$fInfo['file_name'],
                'description' => $this->input->post('description'),
                'status' => $this->input->post('status')
            );
            $check = $this->mdl_inner->add_image($insert);
            if($check){
                $this->session->set_flashdata('success',"Image Added Sucessfully");
                redirect('admin/inner_gallery/add_images/', 'refresh');  
            }
        }else{
            $this->session->set_flashdata('error',"Upload Proper Image Format");
            redirect('admin/inner_gallery/add_images/', 'refresh');
        }
    }
    $arrData['middle'] = 'admin/inner/add_image';
    $this->load->view('admin/template',$arrData);
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

thanks guys but i solve this problem.
 via loading library in constructor

```
 $this->load->library('image_lib');
```

after that added two line code

```
 $this->image_lib->clear();
 $this->image_lib->initialize($img_array);
```

and remove this line

```
 $this->load->library('image_lib', $img_array);
```

my final code is

```
public function add_images(){

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('description','Description','required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('status','Status','required');

    if($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE) {
         // print_r($this->input->post());
        $config['upload_path'] = 'public/img/inner_images/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|jpeg|png';   // upload only valid images            
        // update library setting of upload
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
        //upload image 
        $this->upload->do_upload('image');
        $fInfo = $this->upload->data(); // get all info of uploaded file

        //for image resize
        $img_array = array();
        $img_array['image_library'] = 'gd2';
        $img_array['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
        $img_array['create_thumb'] = TRUE;
        //you need this setting to tell the image lib which image to process
        $img_array['source_image'] = $fInfo['full_path'];
        $img_array['width'] = 113;
        $img_array['height'] = 75;

        $this->image_lib->clear(); // added this line
        $this->image_lib->initialize($img_array); // added this line
        if (!$this->image_lib->resize())
        {
            echo $this->image_lib->display_errors(); exit;
        }
        if($fInfo['file_ext'] ==='.gif'||$fInfo['file_ext'] ==='.jpg'|| $fInfo['file_ext'] ==='.jpeg' || $fInfo['file_ext'] ==='.png'|| $fInfo['file_ext'] ===''){
            $insert = array(
                'inner_image' =>$fInfo['file_name'],
                'description' => $this->input->post('description'),
                'status' => $this->input->post('status')
            );
            $check = $this->mdl_inner->add_image($insert);
            if($check){
                $this->session->set_flashdata('success',"Image Added Sucessfully");
                redirect('admin/inner_gallery/add_images/', 'refresh');  
            }
        }else{
            $this->session->set_flashdata('error',"Upload Proper Image Format");
            redirect('admin/inner_gallery/add_images/', 'refresh');
        }
    }
    $arrData['middle'] = 'admin/inner/add_image';
    $this->load->view('admin/template',$arrData);
}
```