# How to add support gd library to server

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have applied following code. But didn't find any solution. How I can add support gd library to server.

```
public function addreqdoctor()
{
    if($_FILES['userfile']['name']){
        $ext = end(explode(".", $_FILES['userfile']['name']));
        $new_name = time()."_".rand(1,10000).'.'.$ext;
        $basic['picture'] =  $new_name;
        $config['upload_path'] = './doctors/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
        $config['file_name']     =  $new_name;
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
        if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
        {
            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

        }else{
            $this->upload->do_upload();
            $configs['image_library'] = 'gd2';
            $configs['source_image']    = './doctors/'.$new_name;
            $config['new_image'] = './doctors/thumbs/'.$image_name;
            $configs['create_thumb'] = TRUE;
            $configs['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
            $configs['width']   = 80;
            $configs['height']  = 70;

            $this->load->library('image_lib');
            $this->image_lib->initialize($configs);
            $this->image_lib->clear();
            if ( ! $this->image_lib->resize())
            {
                echo $this->image_lib->display_errors();die;
            }
            else{
                $this->image_lib->resize();
            }
        }
    }
```

I have found this error. After uploading file, this error is coming in browser.

```
Your server does not support the GD function required to process this type of image.
```

Comment: Check out this. It has already answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23284912/codeigniter-image-resize-not-working/23285333#23285333

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple things I picked up on is

**This**

```
$config['new_image'] = './doctors/thumbs/'.$image_name;
```

**Should be**

```
$configs['new_image'] = './doctors/thumbs/'.$image_name;
```

**And also try Change this**

`$configs['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;`

**To**

`$configs['maintain_ratio'] = FALSE;`

**Upload_Resize**

Also when when want to get image name use `$this->upload->data();`

**Example**

```
$upload_info = $this->upload->data();

$configs['source_image']    = './doctors/'. $upload_info['file_name'];
$configs['new_image'] = './doctors/thumbs/'. $upload_info['file_name']
```

Comment: Thannks @wolfgang1983

Answer (score 0):

i have found the problem now. I have to remove this code only.

```
  $this->image_lib->clear();
```

Hope this will work for others also.